# If files are in the same folder, add them to each other

Tags: python, numpy, operating-system

I have txt files that consist of numbers in different folders. They will be converted to numpy arrays and concatenated to each other. I have the following script:

```
import numpy as np
import os 

main_directory = "mypath"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(main_directory):
     for name in files:
          if name.endswith(".txt"):
              os.chdir(root)
              ff = os.path.join(root, name)
              text = open(str(ff)).read()
              a = np.array(text.split("\n").split(), dtype=float)
```

Let's assume a, b and c are the  text files in the same folder. I want to do is something like this for each folder:

```
final = my_function(numpy.concatenate([a, b, c])
```

Please note that I don't know the number of text files to be merged.

Comment: So what's the difficulty?  You could collect those `a` arrays in any sort of list combination that you want.

Comment: But how could I only concatenate the files in the same folder ?

Comment: Could you be more specific please ?